# Did I ruin my computer? Does it have a virus? Why can't I boot it up?

Tags: windows-7, boot

My computer just seemed to "crash" yesterday. It had a pop up that stated I needed to activate Windows Update.  I thought that was odd since I had Automatic Updates turned on. But I went to my start screen to look and it was asking there, too.

The updater did 17 out of 18 updates and then froze. Now I cannot even boot up because the screen says

> The program cannot start because %hs is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix.

So when I put in the disc that came with this computer this past summer when new, nothing happens.

Do you have any idea of what happened?

Comment: Sounds like a clean install is in order, unless you know how to boot into a command prompt and run `sfc /scannow`.

Comment: I'd suggest you take it to an expert rather than trying to recover it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

From what you described, it sounds like your computer needed to be restarted in order to finish installing updates it had partially completed. This is normal and isn't a virus. Even if you have automatic updates installed, your computer will still prompt you when it needs to restart in order to complete updating.

Something went wrong with the update (there's no telling what without digging deep into log files and the like), and more than likely a crucial system file was corrupted, leaving your computer in an un-bootable state.

As Daniel R Hicks commented, if you're not comfortable working with command prompt, safe mode, or repair environments, you should probably take your computer to a shop and have them take a look before following any of the below instructions. They will likely be able to repair your computer without losing any of your valuable data.

---

- When your computer first starts up, press the F key that corresponds to the boot options. Many times it will be the F12 key. You will see options that list the devices your computer can try and boot from. Insert your recovery CD and select the DVD or CD drive from those options. Follow the instructions to repair your Windows installation from the disk.
- Try to see if you can boot your computer into Safe Mode. This can be done by turning off the computer, then holding the F8 key while it powers on. You will see several options for Safe Mode, simply use the first one.

  If your computer boots into safe mode, try running a System Restore to the earliest date before you encountered the problem. You can find System Restore by searching for it in the start menu.

  If a System Restore didn't work, boot into Safe Mode again, and instead go to the Start Menu, type `cmd`, then press enter. In the Command Prompt window, enter `sfc /scannow`. This will scan your Windows installation and repair any corrupt system files. Restart. If your computer still doesn't boot normally, then repeat the above steps but instead enter `bootrec /rebuildbcd` at the command prompt and restart.

  If none of these methods work, I would highly suggest taking your computer to an expert.